# kafka_2.10 source is not available

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-kafka

I have the below dependency in pom.xml.
   I need to check the source of some classes for debugging purpose.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But unable to find any source in eclipse, where as sources to other jars are available.

Answer (score 0):

go to inside the project and go to jar file and Right-click on it, then  go to property optopn, in the property you can find 'Java Source Attachment' click 'Workspace' Select the 'src' folder .

[image]

Comment: wo ho Not asking for that :)